# Problems with long term rooting of phone, data loss and OS updates

Tags: rooting, root-access, backup, hardware, unrooting

I'm in the market for a new phone. I use a specific app for internal use that requires the phone to be rooted (or use a MediaTek chipset but they are mostly used in low end-phones and I want a medium-/high-end phone) and this causes me a lot of pain.

Currently I use a Oneplus 6T (before that I had an HTC M9+ - a highend phone with MediaTek) and the problem with this phone is that every update to its firmware "unroots" it (but leaves the internal storage untouched) but when I root the phone after an update the internal storage is **deleted!!!** (Actually, I think the key used for decryption is deleted, but the effect is the same) AFAIK, this is not specific to Oneplus but is how Android typically works.

I have done this twice and lost a lot of data - because the next problem is that there is no, AFAIK, good backup solution for Android that backs up **everything** to **your local computer** and lets you restore the phone after a factory reset (like how iOS-devices work).

So, now when I am about to buy a new phone I am not trying to find the right "hardware" but rather a complete "solution" to my use case. I guess I am looking for the right combination of a custom version of Android with, if necessary, an associated backup solution.

My question is:

- does it exist a version of Android that doesn't "unroot" when updates are applied? (Or always is rooted)

or

- does it exist a version of Android that doesn't factory reset the internal storage when rooted?

or

- does any of the phone manufacturers (or third party) offers a backup solution that backs up **everything** (for example, WiFi-passwords are usually not backed up - they can only be backed up to Google's cloud) to a local computer?

or

- **Any other solution that lets me keep my phone rooted, updated and leaves the internal storage untouched?** (This is actually the main question. The approaches above are just my suggestions for how a solution should work but I am agnostic to how my problem is solved as long as these three conditions - rooted, updated, internal storage untouched - are fulfilled.)

Finally, I don't want to spend a lot of time tweaking my phone and fixing odd problems (i.e., like using a custom version of Linux on a desktop often forces you to do).

Footnote: I have tried Helium for backup but couldn't get it to connect to my computer (a Mac). Besides, it required very old versions of ADB or something like that.

Comment: once device was initial rooted, you can backup all apps and data to pc or external MicroSD Card before each update, no data loss. That's what TWRP, Titanium, Migrate is designed for!? Of course Internal Storage must backup too

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/ota.html

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763